# Event.preventDefault() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#singlechatpanel-1 #sendMessage").click(function(Event)
{
Event.preventDefault();
$("#singlechatpanel-1 .subpanel ul").append('<li><span><img src="./images/chat-thumb.gif"/>Aristona: Test message.</span></li>');
});



<form name="chatForm" id="chatform">
 <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
 <input type="button" name="sendMessage" id="sendMessage" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

When I click on button with mouse, it normally sends the data, but if I press enter while typing something into textbox, page refreshes and URI goes to message?what_I_typed.

How to prevent it? I need to use enter button since it is a chat application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind to the form's submit event instead.

```
$("#chatform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#singlechatpanel-1 .subpanel ul").append('<li><span><img src="./images/chat-thumb.gif"/>Aristona: Test message.</span></li>');
});
```

Comment: 'e' in the function callback is very vague, maybe event?

Comment: Tried all the solutions above, none of them work. Edit: My bad. Form had to be lowercase. F was capital and it was the reason. Thank you for your help mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. add `return false` at the end.

```
$("#singlechatpanel-1 #sendMessage").click(function(Event)
{
   Event.preventDefault();
   $("#singlechatpanel-1 .subpanel ul").append('<li><span><img src="./images/chat-thumb.gif"/>Aristona: Test message.</span></li>');
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#chatform").submit(function(Event) {
  Event.preventDefault();
  $("#singlechatpanel-1 .subpanel ul").append('<li><span><img src="./images/chat-      thumb.gif"/>Aristona: Test message.</span></li>');
});
```

```html
<form name="chatForm" id="chatform">
  <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
  <input type="button" name="sendMessage" id="sendMessage" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

This will help. Put the handler in form submit.